# Wild character in a file path

Tags: c#, wpf

User will follow a convention in naming the image files name. For example, **01_343_UserDescription_987.jpg**, where the numeric code is a constant and user description can be anything. So I can do the following:

```
    foreach (...)
    {
       image[i].Source = new BitmapImage(
           new Uri("C:/Images/0" + i + "_343_" + * + "_987", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

Is there a wildcard character or can I even do that?

Comment: Select all files by this pattern then loop them.

Comment: You're missing the `.jpg` extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An URI has to point to an exact location, not some wildcard that can match to one or many files. You can make this yourself though with a simple extra step:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Images/", $"0{i}_343_*_987");
Uri uri = new Uri(files.Single(), UriKind.Absolute);
```

Not sure if you need the slashes like that, if so use `files.First().Replace('\\', '/')`.

Answer (score 2):

No, a URI can not contain wildcards. But you can use wildcards to get a list of all the files in a directory that follow the pattern:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Images", "0?_343_*_987.jpg");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(file UriKind.Absolute);
    ...
}
```

Please note that I'm using two wildcards here!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a wildcard character or can I even do that?

No, you have to add a first step to find the actual file name, then use that name as constructor argument.

you can take a look at [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)